# angular Manually trigger validation on input

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a template-driven form with an `<input>` bound to `[(ngModel)]` and would like to manually trigger all `Validators` I placed on it, would it be possible ?

If you're interested to know **why** I would like this kind of behavior I would say that in the case of a custom `Validator` with dynamics rules (or dependent of variables) when a rules change we would need to check the `<input>` to seek for errors.

```
<input type="text" customValidator [(ngModel)]="onlyLetters" required />
```